# paperclip won't commit transaction in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 4.2 and when I upload a picture this message appear on terminal :

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/HOL~1/AppData/Local/Temp/92769fe7c40229f4301d6125e0a9e92820180208-6320-1hscpcc.jpg"
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Please be sure that you have imagemagick installed in your system.

Comment: yes it is installed version 7

Comment: Please try to install it with following command: `homebrew install imagemagick@6`. And then run `homebrew link imagemagick@6`.

Comment: i have windows not mac os